# Adding textbox autofilter for number value

Tags: excel, vba

I have pivot table with dynamic data via SQL server query. I want to add textbox that filters that data when I type and the filter I am trying to make is to filter data based on number (what I enter in the textbox) < (values of column).

The VBA code I found is:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim filterInput As Range
    Dim filterRange As Range
    
    Set filterInput = Range("n1")
    Set filterRange = Range("m10:m60000")
    
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & filterInput & "*", _
        VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub
```

Where `Set filterInput = Range("n1")` is the cell thats linked with the textbox, and `Set filterRange = Range("m10:m60000")` is the column range that contains the numbers ( format is number with 2 decimals.

The current result of the macro is

> Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed.

The data in `filterRange = Range("m10:m60000") is [image: data in column]

In the textbox i input number and expect to filter the values in the column to show all less than the number entered.

The textbox is referenced to a cell and in `Set filterInput = Range("n1")` i reference that cell, so what i enter in the textbox is entered in the cell and that works as filterInput.

Comment: What do you try doing using `Criteria` in this way: `"Criteria1:="*" & filterInput & "*""`? How `Range("n1").value` does look against the values in column to be filtered?

Comment: With current criteria i think it searchers for any text i input in the textbox, issue is i dont know what to change so the macro works and filters as i explained. Answer to your question is `filterRange.AutoFilter`, and i set the filter range beforehand.

Comment: Please give an example for `filterInput` where it fails as well as an example of the data in `m10:m60000`

Comment: Your problem is that *you don't know what to change* and ours is that we do not understand what is to be done... I asked you specifically why using that type of Criteria, how the text box looks, but you keep saying that the code does not do what you need. If you cannot help us to help you, it is difficult to really be helped... Please, try showing an example. Range against the filter criteria, followed by your expectations.

Comment: I added more explanation, i hope its understandable now.

Comment: Then, try `filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & filterInput , VisibleDropDown:=False`. This should answer "expect to filter the values in the column to show all less than the number entered"... This is something different than what we could understand  only looking to your initial question.

Comment: I changed it and when i input 3 in the textbox again error > Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed. displayed, when i debuged line `filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & filterInput , VisibleDropDown:=False` was marked yellow.

Comment: Is your range to be filtered formatted as number? Is it possible to be Text formatted?

Comment: Yeah its number.

Comment: It shouldn't behave in that way. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook where you try the code?

Comment: It has sensitive data, so i prefer not sharing publicly, but if you are fine with it i can share it privately with you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What Excel version do you use? You can send the workbook on my private mail (see my profile), but if you send it, please announce me. Otherwise, it will go on Spam... Before that, try inserting the next code line `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` just before the one trying to filter. Does it change anything? Without it, using change event, it will filter after each digit input and the filtering will be done on the existing filtered range, not working as you expect it... But this is not the reason of your error...

Comment: Hi i inboxed you, i tried and error is same. Thank you for the support!

Comment: Ok. I will look at it and tell you where is the problem...

Comment: Sorry, I was out of my office and now I came back. I must leave it in some minutes. I will rapidly look at it and tell you my first impressions.

Comment: Firstly, you did not link the text box to the mentioned cell. I linked it at the necessary one. If  I remember well, it has been linked to M8. 2. The standard `AutoFilter` method does not work on a pivot table. It has its own filtering way. If I remember well, is should be something like `PivotTable.Pivotfields("the heeader").PivotFilters. Add` (or `Add2`). Again, if I remember well, it sets the filter but not activate it for a big number of rows in the processed pivot table. For such a large file, it is not good to use text box `Click` event. It will be triggered by each input digit.

Comment: For instance, if you want filtering for `2.5`, it will firstly filter based on `2`, then it may return an error (or not...) when type `2.` and after that based on the input number. So, three times instead of one. Anyhow, replacing the previous filter and placing the new one should take more then 2 minutes. That's why, I would recommend `DblClick` event. Coming back to the filtering, I remember that I did it by iteration between pivot items and hide them according to the necessary condition. If interested, I can show you how after some hours when I will be home...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next `DblClick` code event in the sheet code module where the text box exists. Then modify the name of the existing `Click` event, in order to make it not being triggered:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim filterInput As Range, p As PivotTable, PF As PivotField, rngHid As Range, pi As PivotItem
    Set p = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PurchaseData")
  
    Set filterInput = Range("N1")
    Set PF = p.PivotFields("StockRotary")
    PF.DataRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide all rows
    For Each pi In PF.PivotItems                'iterate between pivot items:
        If CDbl(pi.Caption) < CDbl(filterInput.Value) Then 'if item value < filterInput value
            If rngHid Is Nothing Then           'if range keeping the rows to be hidden is nothing:
                Set rngHid = pi.DataRange      'set it
            Else
            On Error Resume Next
               Set rngHid = Union(rngHid, pi.DataRange) 'sometimes some pivot items do not return their DataRange, but usually
            On Error GoTo 0                                      'in case of having their address common with others allready being in the range
            End If
       End If
    Next

    If Not rngHid Is Nothing Then rngHid.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Now, writhe the number to be used like filter criteria and double click inside the text box.

The filtering takes about 10 seconds.

If using the existing `Click` event, this one will be triggered by each input digit and for `2.5`the event will be triggered three times...

Please, test it and send some feedback

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tested and got error Type mismatch run-time 13. Line marked in yellow is `If CDbl(pi.Caption) < CDbl(filterInput.Value) Then 'if item value < filterInput value` i guess its issue with the variable types or the decimal separator, but i tried changing the format from , to dot and error showed again. In the textboxt i enter for example 5,55 and click twice inside as i understood then the table is hidden and the error is displayed. The values in column StockRotary are with comma separator.

Comment: @svetozar slavkov Did you try the code on the workbook I sent? If not, did you correct the linked cell address, as I explained in my comments? Do you use the recommended event? Did you try the workbook I sent?

Comment: Yes i did try the file you send i replied on mail. Also tested the click event you sent here and the error i got is type mismatch i also changed the referenced cell as you mentioned. As i said also i guess issue now is the CDBL( ) which converts to double, my values are also double with comma separator, but even after i changed to dot separator the error persisted,

Comment: @svetozar slavkov This may be a problem of localization. it worked on  my computer using decimals, too. If you try integers (without decimals), does it work as it should? If yes, we should focus on processing of the string to be processed. VBA knows only dot (.) as decimal separator. If you tries  using a dot in the textbox, because of the localization it is considered as string, anyhow. But try working with integers and give me a sign. And **you did not understand too well my recommendation regarding to NOT USE CHANGE EVENT**. When you write "3," the string cannot be converted in a `Double`.

Comment: @svetozar slavkov I modified the Region Settings on my computer, using comma instead of dot. In the textbox it stays as dot on using the dot from num pad and everything works smooth. How is it happening in your installation? If still problematic, do you use AnyDesk? If available, I would like to allow remote entering in your computer testing the file to understand what's happening on your installation. Otherwise, I cannot what to believe. I cannot reproduce your problem...